# How can I have a div with multiple children in ActiveAdmin/Arbre

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, arbre

I have this code:

```
div class: item.ui_type do
  link_to image_tag(item.image.image_public_url), item.target)
  link_to item.label, item.target
end
```

Basically, I want a div with 2 links inside. However, only the last element is getting rendered, presumably because what gets rendered inside the body is the return value of the block.

I know I can declare those as an array and join them, but then I need to call html_safe. I'm trying to find a way to do this when you actually don't trust the input that you're receiving.

This seems like it should be an extremely simple thing to do, but I can't find it anywhere.

Any pointers?

Comment: This may help http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Comment: It seems that the next code is working well: `Arbre::Context.new { div class: 'test' do a 'first link', href: 'first_link'; a 'second_link', href: 'second_link' end }`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reason atomdev's example works and Daniel's does not is that `link_to` is a Rails tag helper and `a` is an Arbre tag, see [this similar issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre/issues/46).  Try wrapping `link_to` with `text_node`, `div` or `span`.  It might be worth opening an Arbre GitHub issue for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to add two links inside the `div`

```
div(:class => "some_class") do
  [
    link_to("Link1", link1_path),
    link_to("Link2", link2_path)
  ].join.html_safe
end
```

Behind it does is first, create the link tag in strings inside an array, second, you join these strings and make it html_safe so div can accept it.